# securing - openUI5 running against NON SAP oDATA on Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, sapui5

does anyone have experience with openUI5 running against a non SAP Netweaver Gateway hosted oData Service? (openUi5 itself runs in an different Tomcat)

Can anyone figured out what "best practice" can be in this case regarding authentification to the oData service?

Any ideas regarding session management in the openUI5 App?

thx, regards
Micha

Answer (score 0):

I run many openui5 apps against azure web apis (oData & REST). 
For oData APIs you would have to use oData v2 as v4 is functionally poor at this stage (althought support for v4 is growing fast in the openui5 SDK).

In my openui5 apps I authenticate to an identity provider that provides a JWT token. You could use client-side session management.

In addition there are a number of examples of [using openui5](http://Displaying%20images%20in%20SAPUI5%20received%20from%20the%20Northwind%20OData%20service) with the [northwind odata service](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/) (again if V4 presents problems use V2)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.. may I have another question .. the JWT sounds quite good. But I'm not familiar with it. If I have an IdentityProvider which also works with JWT how I manage this in the openUI5 app? Have I manually put something to the request header in every data request?

Comment: yes.     var headers = {};
    if (token) { headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;}
    // would like to log functional calls to global events

    return $.ajax({
      headers: headers,